# Project Euler 4. Why is my condition evaluating to true when using the .reverse! method on a string in a each loop?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, if-statement

I am currently doing project 4 of Euler where I have to find the highest palindrome number. My idea was to put all the multiples into an array called multiples and change each of these numbers into a string.

Next I was going to loop though this array and push any string that was equal to its reverse to a new array called palindromes. However, for some reason my if statement evaluates for true for every number and I do not know why.

The specific code giving the problem is this

```
multiples.each do |n| #collecting the number of pallidromes    
    if n.reverse!.to_i ==  n.to_i#compare the number
     palindromes.push(n)
    end
  end
```

The whole of the code is as follows:

```
#A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

#Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

def palindrome(bigNum,smallNum)
  i = 1
  palindromes = []
  multiples = []#collecting the number of multiples

  while i <= bigNum
    while smallNum <= bigNum
      multipliedNum = bigNum * smallNum #multiplying each bigNum by each smallNum 
      multipliedNum = multipliedNum.to_s #changing it into a string
      multiples.push(multipliedNum) #adding it an array
      smallNum += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end

  multiples.each do |n| #collecting the number of pallidromes    
    if n.reverse!.to_i ==  n.to_i#compare the number
     palindromes.push(n)
    end
  end
  puts palindromes.inspect
  puts palindromes.count
  puts multiples[-1]

end

palindrome(999,100)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Just use `reverse` without `!`

Comment: Tried that already but it evaluates to false instead. I am unsure why it does evaluate to true as there is a definite palindrome in the multiple array

Answer (score 1):

```
if n.reverse!.to_i ==  n.to_i
```

You are using the bang version `String#reverse!`, which means `n` is modified to its reverse. For example, if `n` is `'123'` at the start, then `n.reverse!` evaluates as `'321'`, in the same time, `n` has also been modified to `'321'`.

Change it to:

```
if n.reverse.to_i ==  n.to_i
```

Comment: Hi. Yes I tried that already but it seems to make evaluate to false for ever number which is quite strange. I have also tried putting it in a variable before the condition but still the same result.

Comment: @new2code Then there's some other bug in your code. `n = '121'; puts n.reverse == '121' # true`.

Comment: @new2code The code to calculate `multiples` is wrong. Try `999.downto(100) do |a|
  999.downto(100) do |b|
    num = a * b`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much Yu Hao. My loop logic was indeed incorrect. I was just sure it was correct. You really pushed me in the right direction without telling me what to do. Thank you so much.